# Cross Domain AJAX to Amazon S3 on Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The following request works in Firefox but not in Chrome:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://pucquepariu.s3.amazonaws.com/exercicios/1/INF1005-Site-1-1-solucao.c?1366303788',
    success:function(data){
        alert(data)
    }
})
```

Here is my CORS configuration on my Amazon AWS S3 bucket:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>Content-Type,Depth,User-Agent,X-File-Size,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,X-File-Name,Cache-Control</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

Had to use the `crossDomain: true` option on the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://pucquepariu.s3.amazonaws.com/exercicios/1/INF1005-Site-1-1-solucao.c?1366303788',
    crossDomain: true,
    success:function(data){
        alert(data)
    }
})
```

Comment: If you can, explain your fix more thoroughly and accept your own answer!

Comment: Expanded the answer. Gotta wait two days to accept my own answer, though!